Can the message space for Ajtai Hash be extened?
I have a question regarding the Ajtai hash function. Typically, the message space for this function is the binary space $\{0, 1\}^m$. However, I am considering extending the message space to $\{-1,0, 1\}^m$ or $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}^{m}$. Is this modification feasible?
The security of the Ajtai hash function appears to be reduced to the SIS/CVP problem. I feel that this modification might be feasible if appropriate parameters are chosen, but I am not certain.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Any reason why re-encoding ${-1,0,1}^m$ to ${0, 1}^{2m}$ by some convention like -1↦11, 0↦00, 1↦01 would not do? Or more generally ${-k,…,-1,0,1,…k}^m$ to ${0, 1}^{\lceil1+\log_2k\rceil;!m}$ ?

I am attempting to design a privacy-preserving protocol involving zero-knowledge proofs and Ajtai hash. The private information lies in the space ${-1, 0, 1}^m$. Recoding this space into ${0, 1}^{2m}$ may introduce additional proof overhead. @fgrieu

$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$Yes, the proof of Ajtai's hash functions works essentially by arguing that if we have two different vectors $\vec{x}\neq\vec{y}$ such that $\vec{x} \vec{A}=\vec{x} \vec{A}$ then we have that $(\vec{x}-\vec{y}) \vec{A} = \vec{x} \vec{A} - \vec{y} \vec{A} = \vec{0}$ and thus any collision gives us a vector $\vec{s} = \vec{x}-\vec{y}$ such that $\vec{s}\vec{A}=\vec{0
}$ and $\Vert \vec{s}\Vert = \Vert \vec{x} - \vec{y}\Vert \leq \Vert \vec{x}\Vert +\Vert \vec{y}\Vert$, solving SIS for norm bound $\max_{\vec{x},\vec{y}}\{\Vert \vec{x}\Vert +\Vert \vec{y}\Vert\}$.
This proof works independently of the set $x,y$ are chosen from. The only thing this influences is what the norm bound of the SIS problem you're reducing from is.
For $\{0,1\}$ the bound will be $2$ for infinity norm and $2\sqrt{n}$ for euclidean norm. You'll note that going to balanced ternary, i.e. $\{-1,0,1\}$ we don't actually lose anything, the norm bounds are still $2$ for infinity norm and $2\sqrt{n}$ for euclidean norm.
For arbitrary balanced $(2\alpha+1)$-ary, i.e. $\{-\alpha,\dots,\alpha\}$ you'll get $2\alpha$ for infinity norm and $2\alpha\sqrt{n}$ for euclidean norm.
So increasing the arity will require increasing the norm bound in your SIS assumption, but asssuming that you're choosing your parameters appropriately, that's not an issue.

thank you very much : )

It's worth mentioning that what you want holds not only for the Ajtai hash, but for the extension of it to the ring setting as well. This was actually established in the initial set of papers by Micciancio introducing the ring setting, see for example Section 5 of Generalized Compact Lattices are Collision Resistant by Lyubashevesky and Micciancio, or Section 4 of Generalized Compact Knapsacks, Cyclic Lattices, and Efficient One Way Functions by Micciancio.

thanks for your help :)
